# How to fill text with 2 different color/texture

Tags: c#, .net, gdi+, gdi

I draw text on top of a image using Path.Addstring and filling it with a color and it works perfectly. Now I would like to split(bisect) the text vertically and have 2 different colors or textures. For eg. the top half of the text with a solid brush and the bottom half with hatch brush. I'd like to know if this is possible and which way should I implement it.

Reference image created using paint.net software. I drew a line to split the text and filled the bottom part with a different texture.

[image: Text]

*I don't want the line to be visible in the final output.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Possible.

1. Fill the path with the solid brush.
2. Get the rectangle that bounds the path through the [`GraphicsPath.GetBounds`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.drawing.drawing2d.graphicspath.getbounds?view=dotnet-plat-ext-6.0) method.
3. Call the [`Graphics.SetClip`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.drawing.graphics.setclip?view=dotnet-plat-ext-6.0) method to exclude the top half of the rectangle.
4. Fill the path with a `TextureBrush` or `HatchBrush`.

An example that uses a [HatchBrush](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.drawing.drawing2d.hatchbrush?view=dotnet-plat-ext-6.0) to fill the second vertical half of the path.

```cs
private void SomeControl_Paint(object sender, PaintEventArgs e)
{
    var g = e.Graphics;
    var r = (sender as Control).ClientRectangle;
            
    using (var gp = new GraphicsPath())
    using (var sf = new StringFormat())
    using (var fnt = new Font("Blackoak Std", 72))
    using (var hbr = new HatchBrush(HatchStyle.Percent25, Color.White, Color.Red))
    {
        sf.Alignment = sf.LineAlignment = StringAlignment.Center;

        gp.AddString("RED", fnt.FontFamily, (int)fnt.Style, GetEmFontSize(fnt), r, sf);

        g.SmoothingMode = SmoothingMode.AntiAlias;
        g.FillPath(Brushes.Red, gp);

        var rf = gp.GetBounds();
        rf.Height /= 2f;

        g.SetClip(rf, CombineMode.Exclude);
        g.FillPath(hbr, gp);
        g.ResetClip();
        g.SmoothingMode = SmoothingMode.None;
    }
}

private float GetEmFontSize(Font fnt) =>
    fnt.SizeInPoints * (fnt.FontFamily.GetCellAscent(fnt.Style) + 
    fnt.FontFamily.GetCellDescent(fnt.Style)) / fnt.FontFamily.GetEmHeight(fnt.Style);
```

See also the other [HatchStyle](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.drawing.drawing2d.hatchstyle?view=dotnet-plat-ext-6.0) values.

[image: SOQ72225088A]

[image: SOQ72225088B]